# If the sample space is an Euclidean Space, we can use a different type of PDF

Tags: probability-theory, definition, density-function

The title resume all the point I'll try to make now. Reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476568/strange-definitions-about-basic-probability-need-clarification/1580395#comment3335933_1580395) post, I realize that is possible to have *another* type of PDF (probability density function).

Usually, we have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, a random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ and the PDF of $X$, $f_X:\mathbb{R}\to[0, \infty)$. The whole point of the PDF is that we can integrate it over any borel set $A$ (contained in the codomain of $X$) and get the probability $ P[X\in A] = \int_A f_X\ dx$.

What about the case when we have that $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is the Borel sigma algebra over $\mathbb{R}$? Looks like it's easier to define the PDF to be a function $f:\Omega\to[0,\infty)$ such that $P[A] = \int_A f\ dx$. So we still can use this PDF to get the probability of events via integration over borel sets. The idea in the book (mentioned on the other post) is that $\Omega$ can be a manifold, so we integrate the PDF over a subset contained in this manifold to get the probability of that subset. If $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is a random variable (not necessarily the map $x\to x$), we could talk about $f_X$, the PDF of $X$, such as described before. But in this sample space, we can use the *other* PDF $f$. So, instead calculating $\int_Af_X\ dx = P[X\in A]$, we can calculate $\int_{\{X\in A\}}f\ dx = P[X\in A]$. Note that the first integral is over the codomain of $X$, but the second is over the sample space $\Omega$.

I want to know if there is some technical detail I should be aware of and how common is this. Thank you!

**PS:** this idea can be extended to $\Omega$ being any Euclidean Space.

**EDIT:** [This](http://www.ams.org/notices/200511/what-is.pdf) article in particular is an example of what I'm saying. Instead defining real random variables $X_{ij}$ as the entries of a random matrix, it's possible to see the sample space as $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and **define** a probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ to work with.

Comment: The $f$ that you describe in the third part of your question is actually the PDF of random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $x\mapsto x$. In that situation we have $\{X\in A\}=A$. There is no need for and no profit in a different sort of PDF. That will only provide confusion.

Comment: @drhab but is there some need in defining this random variable $x \to x$?

Comment: "Need" is a heavy word, but there is no profit at all in *not* doing it (or can you mention any?). I plead for an equal treatment of *every* random variable to avoid any confusion.  What follows after "we can calculate" hardly deserves the term calculation. It is more like finding out the probability of set $X^{-1}(A)$  on base of how this probability is defined. It might happen that such $f$ doesn't even exist, i.e. $P$ is not absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @drhab In this scenario, $f$ is **defined** as being a function such that $\int_A f\ dx = P[A]$ for any borel set $A$ in the sample space. Clearly if $m(A) = 0$, then $\int_A f\ dx = 0$, therefore $P[A] = 0$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Well, okay. Then the remark about absolutely continuous does not apply on this scenario. My main objection was and is: no need, no profit and a source of confusion.

Comment: In the other post mentioned, the sample space is a subset (I read it is a manifold) of $\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{S}^{n_1}\times\ldots\times\mathbb{S}^{n_k}$. So they use this type of PDF to calculate the probabilities via integration on manifolds (the manifold is the sample space, not the codomain of the random variable). I think the idea is to use the geometric properties of the sample space to get the probabilities. It's not every time that your sample space is something you can integrate over, so when it is, I think it makes sense to try to define the PDF directly on the sample space.

Comment: The authors of this book did this approach, I thought this idea would be something more accepted in general. Maybe I'm wrong.